# Using requestAnimationFrame() as setInterval() Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, web, setinterval, requestanimationframe

I am currently in a situation where I am using setInterval() in order to create buttons which flicker at particular frequencies on screen. Like so: (element refers to the button)

```
setInterval(function() { 
   if($(element).css("background-color") === darkColor){ //if colour is dark
       $(element).css("background-color", lightColor); //set to light

   }else if($(element).css("background-color") === lightColor){ //if colour is light
       $(element).css("background-color", darkColor); //set to dark
   }
}, frequency); //frequency value is in milliseconds
```

I lately read on the Internet that requestAnimationFrame() function is generally better for displaying timed on-screen animations. Do you know how requestAnimationFrame() can be used in such a situation or if it is even suitable to use it in such a situation?

Note: It is mandatory that Javascript is used to perform the flicker effect (no CSS)

Thank you

Comment: For CSS, you should just use [CSS Animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations).

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot do so in such a case as it is required to use Javascript to create the flicker effect. @zero298

Comment: you just self-call at the end of the function, but you really really should use CSS instead

Comment: @Questionnaire "It is required" by what? CSS animations are pretty flexible…

Comment: It is an assignment task which I have to do that's why it is required :) @duskwuff

Comment: @dandavis Could you give me a sample code as how you would implement it please? As I don't really understand what you mean.

Comment: change `function()` to `function a()`, then `},` to `requestAnimationFrame(a);},`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `requestAnimationFrame()` by giving it a function reference.  If you want to continuously call it with the same function, have the function recursively schedule another `requestAnimationFrame()`, it doesn't continuously fire as `setInterval()` does, it acts more like `setTimeout()`.

If you want to delay the next request, then you aren't really getting a benefit over `setInterval` or `setTimeout` because you still have to schedule the next animation frame request after an amount of time.  `requestAnimationFrame()` just says, "Hey browser, next time you go to paint the window, run this function while you're at it."

You're going to run into issues comparing colors like this.  You might get an `rgb(n, n, n)` in some cases or maybe a hex string in others.  I don't know the API specs.

**Warning, the examples below will flicker colors very fast**

```js
function change() {
  if ($("#foo").css("background-color") === "rgb(0, 128, 0)") {
    $("#foo").css("background-color", "rgb(128, 0, 0)");
  } else {
    $("#foo").css("background-color", "green");
  }
  
  setTimeout(()=>requestAnimationFrame(change), 500);
}

$("#foo").css("background-color", "red");
requestAnimationFrame(change);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="foo">M</span>
```

Also, I **really** would suggest you using CSS animations instead.

```css
#foo {
  animation: 500ms flicker infinite steps(1);
}

@keyframes flicker {
  0% {
    background-color: rgb(256, 0, 0);
  }
  50% {
    background-color: rgb(0, 256, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<span id="foo">M</span>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. However, this does not solve my problem. As I still need to be able to control when the flicker happens and not just let it depend on the screen's refresh rate. I need specific timings which will result in specific frequencies. Therefore a time must be specified to control when the flicker happens, for example every 0.4 seconds there will be a colour change.